# Do Java sockets support full duplex?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Is it possible to have one thread write to the `OutputStream` of a Java `Socket`, while another reads from the socket's `InputStream`, without the threads having to synchronize on the socket?

Comment: I wish this sort of information was readily available to developers via the Javadoc.

Comment: "threadsafe" is not a proper term here. it's more like "full duplex". it's safe to have 2 threads, one for read, one for write.

Comment: at of curiosity what are you trying to do? If you are looking to do non blocking networking have you checked out http://mina.apache.org/ ? It probably doesn't fit your needs but worth looking at.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the link, the Mina framework is probably more extensive than the simple IPC in my case.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sure. The exact situation you're describing shouldn't be a problem (reading and writing simultaneously).

Generally, the reading thread will block if there's nothing to read, and might timeout on the read operation if you've got a timeout specified.

Since the input stream and the output stream are separate objects within the Socket, the only thing you might concern yourself with is, what happens if you had 2 threads trying to read or write (two threads, same input/output stream) at the same time? The read/write methods of the InputStream/OutputStream classes are not synchronized. It is possible, however, that if you're using a sub-class of InputStream/OutputStream, that the reading/writing methods you're calling are synchronized. You can check the javadoc for whatever class/methods you're calling, and find that out pretty quick.

Comment: I don't understand how both are possible simultaneously since `accept()` method (in case of ServerSocket) is a blocking method... So reading/writing thread can't acquire the socket at the same time.... Nevertheless, if I'm mistaken, do sent/received data not mixed up in the pipe ?

Comment: accept() creates a new client socket. That's separate from reading/writing. 

Also there's two streams - an input stream and an output stream - so the data doesn't mix.

Comment: Okay..two streams!!  I understand it better now... Thank You

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's safe.

If you wanted more than one thread reading from the InputStream you would have to be more careful (assuming you are reading more than one byte at a time).