# what is the fastest way to write a byte array to socket outputstream in java

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

As the title, and assume the size of byte array is no larger than 16 Kbytes.

Currently I am implementing a middleware for MySQL (like MySQL Proxy), which requires high throughput. but the overhead caused by reading data from socket and writing data to socket. For now, I use

```
in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
```

and

```
out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))
```

When read data and write, I use

`in.read(byte[] b)` and `out.write(byte[] b, int offset, int len)` with `out.flush()`

Can anyone tell me a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing byte arrays it doesn't make much difference. The network is the limiting factor, not the API. I think you're already doing  it near-optimally. The most significant factor is the size of your socket send buffer in the kernel, and the socket receive buffer at the receiver.

You could investigate NIO and direct buffers, but I doubt  you'll see a significant difference. Direct buffers are really for the case where you're just copying between channels, and the rest of NIO is really about scalability rather than performance over an individual channel.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just forwarding bytes, you could save a little time by not using DataInputStream, and instead just using BufferedInputStream.read() and BufferedOutputStream.write().

Comment: I did use BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream before but it was worse than what I use now. BTW, my program also needs to read the data before forwarding them.

Answer (score 0):

As EJP mentions, the network is the limiting factor. But that did not stop me trying to make the fastest implementation I could imagine without using NIO. The thing is, you can read from a socket while you write to another/[the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6265731/3080094) socket. One thread cannot do this (either reads or writes) so multiple threads are needed. But without NIO, that requires a lot of threads (mostly sitting idle waiting on I/O though). NIO is a bit more complicated but is very good at using very few threads when there are a lot of connections with low volume (see the summary on [this page](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) of the article that Baldy mentions).

Anyway, below a non-NIO test class that you can update and use to see for yourself what is (not) the limiting factor.

```
public class SocketForwarder {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        new SocketForwarder().forward();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static final int portNumber = 54321;
public static final int maxSend = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100 MB
public static final int bufSize = 16 * 1024;
public static final int maxBufInMem = 128;

private static final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

private final ExecutorService tp = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private final ArrayBlockingQueue<byte[]> bq = new ArrayBlockingQueue<byte[]>(maxBufInMem); 
private final CountDownLatch allReceived = new CountDownLatch(1);
private Socket from, to, sender, receiver;
private int bytesSend, bytesReceived;

public void forward() throws Exception {

    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ServerSocket ss = null;
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                from = ss.accept();
                to = ss.accept();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try { ss.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
            }
        }
    });

    sender = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);
    receiver = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);

    // Setup proxy reader.
    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
            try {
                InputStream in = from.getInputStream();
                int l = 0;
                while ((l = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    byte[] bufq = new byte[l];
                    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, bufq, 0, l);
                    bq.put(bufq);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    // Setup proxy writer.
    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                OutputStream out = to.getOutputStream();
                while (true) {
                    byte[] bufq = bq.take();
                    out.write(bufq);
                    out.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    // Start receiver.
    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
            try {
                InputStream in = receiver.getInputStream();
                int l = 0;
                while (bytesReceived < maxSend && (l = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    bytesReceived += l;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(df.format(new Date()) + " bytes received: " + bytesReceived);
            allReceived.countDown();
        }
    });
    // Start sender.
    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            try {
                OutputStream out = sender.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println(df.format(new Date())  + " start sending.");
                while (bytesSend < maxSend) {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[random.nextInt(bufSize)];
                    out.write(buf);
                    out.flush();
                    bytesSend += buf.length;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Bytes send: " + bytesSend);
        }
    });
    try { 
        allReceived.await();
    } finally {
        close(sender);
        close(from);
        close(to);
        close(receiver);
        tp.shutdownNow();
    }
}

private static void close(Socket s) {
    try { s.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {} 
}

}
```

It took my computer 2 seconds to transfer 100MB locally, expect a lot less when a network is involved.

Answer (score -1):

For the best throughput you're going to want to use NIO and ByteBuffers. NIO keeps most of the work reading and writing to the sockets in native code and so can be much faster.

It is more complex to write good NIO code but depending on what kind of performance you're looking for, it can be worth the effort.

There are some good NIO examples out there along with some good introductions and comparisons. One resource I've used is http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html.

Comment: java.net also 'keeps most of the work reading and writing to the sockets in native code'. That's the only place it can be. Java has to call the C sockets API: it doesn't have its own. NIO isn't 'much faster' for that reason, and really isn't faster at all in most circumstances.

Comment: Normal java sockets have to copy the data streams between native code and JVM buffers. NIO keeps the data in native code avoiding JVM marshaling. When you add selectors in and avoid a bunch of thread overhead then for the purpose of a proxy as mentioned by the OP, NIO will be faster. If, on the other hand, his application is modifying the data stream (not what he said) then NIO is of no benefit.