# Java port forwarding performance

Tags: java, performance, sockets, port, sftp

**Init**
I have implemented a very basic port forwarding application, which takes inputs from the client and post it to a remote sftp server.

Sockets:

```
socket sock = server_sock.accept()
Socket client_sock = new Socket("remote sfpt server host",port);
client_sock.connect();
```

And input/output streams from each of these sockets are then copied using the following logic.

Copy:

```
byte b[] = new byte[65535];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead =in.read(b)) >= 0){
    out.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
    out.flush();
}
```

**Problem**

1. Both sftp server and the basic port forwarding server are hosted on
   the same machine.
2. Directly connecting to the sftp server, I can transfer a file at around 30MB/s, whereas
3. Transferring a file via the port forwarding server is always pegged at ~3MB/s-4MB/s.
4. I have tried with ServerSocketChannel as well but performance was
   same.

**Question is** how can I improve this basic port forwarding server's performance at per the sftp server?

Comment: Hmm, a 64k buffer probably isn't going to help;  network MTU is around 1500 bytes max.  How about your [Receive Window size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_tuning#Window_size) and your OS buffers, what's the max receive window compared to the sftp server?

Comment: You used a huge buffer, don't

Comment: Tried till 8MB of buffer, no improvement at all.
plus, tried setting setReceiveBufferSize for server[before binding] as well.

Comment: I suggest you use blocking NIO with an off heap/direct buffer.  You should be able to pass data at a rate of GB/s over loopback this way.

Comment: Read while you write, don't block writing when reading. I have posted a forwarder with good performance before, you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23689356/3080094).